# Verb form for the word "ubiquitous or widespread"

Tags: single-word-requests

the sentence I am trying to create is used everywhere in this report I am trying to proofread and semantically goes like this: "Increasing the use of internet" or "making infrastructure establishment widespread across the nation"
I am looking for a verb more practical than "making sth. widespread" or a proper verb version of "ubiquitous"
I have used "spreading" but it just does not sound correct to my ear.

I'd be glad to get some answers. Thank you.

Comment: I think I am gonna go with :"Increasing the ubiquity of Internet broadband infrastructures"  Does it sound correct to a native's ear?

Comment: No. Ubiquitous means everywhere. If something is everywhere, there's nowhere it isn’t.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the examples you have provided (and I am under the impression that you have several sentences where you would need an array of such words to avoid redundancy), I would suggest:

```
- disseminate
: spread (something, especially information) widely.

- universalize
: bring into universal use; make available for all.

- promulgate
: Promote or make widely known (an idea or cause)

- popularize
: Cause (something) to become generally liked.

- propagate
: Spread and promote (an idea, theory, etc.) widely.

- disperse
: Distribute or spread over a wide area
Example: disperse the news (archaic)
```

Definitions taken from [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com).

You have not provided many sentences, hence choosing an appropriate word among the aforementioned ones highly depends on the sentence in question (and of course the context). So make sure you double-check the definitions in at least one more dictionary (e.g. Webster).

Comment: "... propagate infrastructure establishment across the nation ..." sounds pretty good. Promulgate is not as current.

Comment: disseminate : searched and never came across it is used for the purpose other than "organizedly circulating a message, a data"

universalize : making sth. widespread in "entire world"

Comment: Based on the `Internet` example, I must say that `universalize` is an appropriate choice.

Comment: wouldn't you agree that "Universalize" refers to "whole globe" other than "country-wide" ?

Comment: Popularize also a good choice but with only one nuance difference: popularize: to make sth. popular, likeable by a group. I am not sure...

Comment: @Valance I am not so sure.  to my ear it sounds stilted.  But it may have the right meaning.

Comment: I believe you are overthinking this a bit: for example, by definition, `ubiquitous` means `present, appearing, or found everywhere.` Should we then assume that `everywhere` refers to the whole globe, the whole universe, or the whole country? Personally, I do not see a problem with `universalize` used to refer to a nation-wide ubiquity.

Answer (score 0):

Creating [pervasive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pervasive) Internet infrastructure

> Knowledge networks have become pervasive because they can be simple to implement. (Ibid.)

Comment: I researched the word "dissemination" and I thought it only make sense when used before non-tangible nouns such as "idea, opinion etc."

Is it safe to use it in a sentence such like "dissemination of broadband internet infrastructures country-wide" ?

Comment: @Kemal No, it's not just for non-tangible stuff. Oxford Living Dictionaries says: 1.Spread (something, especially information), then it's number two definition refers to cancer spreading.

Comment: @Kemal The comment seems to be meant for another answer.

Answer (score 0):

universalise

> universalise
>   1.1 Bring into universal use; make available for all. ‘attempts to universalize basic education’
>  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/universalize)

Not sure if universalise is too strong a word, in the sense that it means it's everywhere.

If you're talking about infrastructure, as in rolling out a new traffic control system, or broadband network, or social welfare system, I'd probably use:

> "standardise"

instead of any other words meaning "to spread" or "make prevalent".

Comment: standardize sounds like making 2 or more things to have more bases in common. How about commonize? is that even a used word?

Comment: @Kemal Commonize? I would have said no, but Merriam-Webster, Wiktionary and Urban Dictionary have it. If you want something like "commonize" then a good word is "popularise", given in another answer. I would say popularise ideas, values, fashion, computers or internet, but not many cases of infrastructure such as a transnational railway network or universal health care, in these cases the government/council/municipality is implementing/instituting/constructing these things, not so much popularising them.

Answer (score 0):

"Rollout" -is one term currently used for IT infrastructures and networks. So, for  "making infrastructure establishment widespread across the nation", you might try something like: "rolling out widespread internet infrastructures and networks..."
...

Answer (score 0):

Your second example illustrates a common problem with writing in English.  Many writers seem to prefer abstract nouns, coupled with some ‘placeholder’ verb like ‘do’ or ‘make’.  So

> ..., making infrastructure establishment widespread across the nation.

But, as in mathematical equations we should seek to simplify to the greatest extent, so in writing we should seek to simplify.

So “... to make the establishment (of something) ...” in your context is none other than our friend the real verb “to establish (something)”.

What do we want to establish?  “...the infrastructure”.  This noun can take its proper place as object of the verb, instead of languishing as a virtual adjective.

How do we want to establish the infrastructure?  “... throughout the nation.”

So how about this?

> “...establishing the infrastructure throughout the nation.”